# tablesorter pager makes the table hidden

Tags: tablesorter

If I sort my table the content of the table is disabled...
I don't know why. Without the pager it works.

Have somebody the same problem?

```
    $(function() {
    $("table")
        .tablesorter({widthFixed: false, widgets: ['zebra']})
        .tablesorterPager({
            container: $("#pager"),
            size: 25
            });
});
```

Comment: @edit: after click on one header the tbody is empty... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tablesorter's pager plugin completely removes all non-visible rows from the table. So if you want to bind to any elements inside of the table, use the `on()` or `delegate()` function as follows ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)):

```
$(elements).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(elements).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

if that doesn't solve the issue, then please share a demo or some of the code you are having trouble with so we can better help you.